# d3 setinterval animate text and remove image on button click

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, transition, setinterval

Hi I have a click button event to start a setinterval / clear interval animation of some text and to also add an image on a button click. I would like help in how to better stop and remove the animating text and remove the image when a new button is clicked. At the moment the text is replaced by an empty string when the array ends. the image just duplicates each time I click the button.

I have looked at examples that use exit().remove() or merge but I can't work out how to apply it in my case. My code uses D3 nest and is part of a much larger map project using svg and d3.line and other transitioning elements elements.

This is a simplified sample of my D3 code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

  <style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="container">

  <div id ="mapdata"></div>
  <div id = "buttons"></div>

</div>

<script>


d3.queue()

  .defer(d3.csv, "data/testData.csv")
  .await(ready);

function ready (error, data){

var dataGroup = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {return d.year;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .key(function(d){return d.VoyageID;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .entries(data);

dataGroup.forEach(function(yearObject,i) {

var buttons = d3.select("#buttons").selectAll("button")
    .data(dataGroup)
    .enter()
    .append("button")
    .attr("class", "buttons")
    .attr("data-group", function(d){return d.key})
    .attr("id", function(d){return "button_" + d.key})
    .append("label")
    .text(function(d){return d.key;})


var testData = d3.select("#mapdata").selectAll(".voyageData")
    .data(dataGroup)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "voyageData")
    .attr("data-group", function(d){return d.key})
    .attr("id", function(d){return "voyageText_" + d.key})

    var data = testData.selectAll(".data")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "data")
    .attr("id", function(d){return "data_" + d.key})

    var images = testData.selectAll(".images")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
    images.exit().remove();
    images.enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "images")
    .attr("id", function(d){return "images_" + d.key})


//buttons
d3.select("#button_1906").on("click", function(d){
  clickButton(d,i);
});
d3.select("#button_1845").on("click", function(d){
  clickButton(d,i);
});

function clickButton(d,i) {
var voyageClass = d.key;

var voyageID = d.values[0].key;


//animate place name and dates
var j = 0;
var animation = setInterval(function(){

  d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID)
    .text(function(d) { return d.values[j].arrivalDateTxt +" "+d.values[j].placeName; });

        j = j + 1;

        if(j==d.values[0].values.length)
         clearInterval(animation)
           if(j==d.values[0].values.length)
           d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID)
           .text("") // is there a better way to stop or remove text on completion of animation? I am just replacing it with an empty string.
       },1000);

//add image
d3.select("#images_" + voyageID)
       .append("img")
       .attr("src", function(d){return  d.values[j].groupPic })
       .attr("width", "40")
       //how do I remove image on completion of animation or click of new button?

}

  });

}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my sample csv:

```
VoyageID,arrivalDateTxt,year,placeName,groupPic
1,14 January 1906,1906,Place 1,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,1 May 1907,1906,Place 2,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,26 October 1907,1906,Place 3,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,4 November 1907,1906,Place 4,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,26 November 1907,1906,Place 5,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,3 December 1907,1906,Place 6,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,10 December 1907,1906,Place 7,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,20 December 1907,1906,Place 8,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,26 December 1907,1906,Place 9,ANMS1113[006].jpg
3,12 March 1845,1845,Island 1,00038301_4.jpg
3,15 March 1845,1845,Island 2,00038301_4.jpg
3,22 March 1845,1845,Place in ocean 3,00038301_4.jpg
3,23 July 1845,1845,Place in ocean 4,00038301_4.jpg
3,19 December 1845,1845,Place in ocean 5,00038301_4.jpg
3,22 January 1846,1845,Place in ocean 6,00038301_4.jpg
3,30 January 1846,1845,Back home,00038301_4.jpg
```

I am very much hoping someone can help me and help me to improve my code in a more D3 way.

Thanks in advance, Sally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove the image on completion you can use:

```
//animate place name and dates
var j = 0;
var animation = setInterval(function(){

  d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID)
    .text(function(d) { return d.values[j].arrivalDateTxt +" "+d.values[j].placeName; });

  j = j + 1;

  if(j==d.values[0].values.length) {
    clearInterval(animation);
    d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID).text("");
    d3.select("#images_" + voyageID).select("img").remove();
  }
},1000);
```

Setting the `.text("")` restores the state/DOM as before the animation, so I see no problems with that.

To stop the animation you have to keep track of the previous animation

```
var runningAnimation = null;

function stopAnimation(animation, voyageID) {
  clearInterval(animation);
  d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID).text(""); // is there a better way to stop or remove text on completion of animation? I am just replacing it with an empty string.
  d3.select("#images_" + voyageID).select("img").remove();
  runningAnimation = null;
}

function clickButton(d,i) {

  if (runningAnimation) { stopAnimation(runningAnimation.animation, runningAnimation.voyageID); }

  var voyageClass = d.key;

  var voyageID = d.values[0].key;

  //animate place name and dates
  var j = 0;
  var animation = setInterval(function(){

    d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID)
      .text(function(d) { return d.values[j].arrivalDateTxt +" "+d.values[j].placeName; });

    j = j + 1;

    if(j==d.values[0].values.length) { stopAnimation(animation, voyageID); }
  },1000);

  runningAnimation = { animation: animation, voyageID: voyageID };

  //add image
  d3.select("#images_" + voyageID)
    .append("img")
    .attr("src", function(d){return  d.values[j].groupPic })
    .attr("width", "40");
}
```

Setting the button click handler can be simplified

```
buttons.on("click", clickButton);
//buttons
// d3.select("#button_1906").on("click", function(d){
//   clickButton(d,i);
// });
// d3.select("#button_1845").on("click", function(d){
//   clickButton(d,i);
// });
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for this - it works perfectly for me.