# d3 change button style when setinterval animation finishes

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm following on from this d3 js example [d3 setinterval animate text and remove image on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096428/d3-setinterval-animate-text-and-remove-image-on-button-click/52097416#52097416). I'd like to change the background color of the button when the animation stops - to remove the focus from that button and set the buttons back to how they were before they were moused over or clicked and the animation started. I have tried to include this in the stopanimation function but I am not getting the result I am looking for.

In my full code I have included a mouseout function to change the background color of the button but I would really like to tie it to the transition / animation so that it changes when the animation finishes, like I can remove the text and image.

I'm hoping someone will be able to help with this. Thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

  <style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="container">

  <div id ="mapdata"></div>
  <div id = "buttons"></div>

</div>

<script>


d3.queue()

  .defer(d3.csv, "data/testData.csv")
  .await(ready);

function ready (error, data){

var dataGroup = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {return d.year;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .key(function(d){return d.VoyageID;}).sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .entries(data);

dataGroup.forEach(function(yearObject,i) {

var buttons = d3.select("#buttons").selectAll("button")
    .data(dataGroup)
    .enter()
    .append("button")
    .attr("class", "buttons")
    .attr("id", function(d){return "button_" + d.key})
    .append("label")
    .text(function(d){return d.key;})


var testData = d3.select("#mapdata").selectAll(".voyageData")
    .data(dataGroup)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "voyageData")
    .attr("id", function(d){return "voyageText_" + d.key})

    var data = testData.selectAll(".data")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "data")
    .attr("id", function(d){return "data_" + d.key})

    var images = testData.selectAll(".images")
    .data(function(d) {return d.values;})
    images.exit().remove();
    images.enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "images")
    .attr("id", function(d){return "images_" + d.key})


//buttons
buttons.on("mouseover", clickButton);
var runningAnimation = null;

function stopAnimation(animation, voyageID, voyageClass) {
  clearInterval(animation);
  d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID).text("");
  d3.select("#images_" + voyageID).select("img").remove();
  d3.select("#button_" + voyageClass).style("background-color", "red");
  runningAnimation = null;
}

function clickButton(d,i) {

  var voyageClass = d.key;
  var voyageID = d.values[0].key;

 d3.select("#button_" + voyageClass).style("background-color", "green")

  if (runningAnimation) { stopAnimation(runningAnimation.animation, runningAnimation.voyageID, runningAnimation.voyageClass); }

  //animate place name and dates
  var j = 0;
  var animation = setInterval(function(){

    d3.select("#data_"+ voyageID)
      .text(function(d) { return d.values[j].arrivalDateTxt +" "+d.values[j].placeName; });

    j = j + 1;

    if(j==d.values[0].values.length) { stopAnimation(animation, voyageID, voyageClass); }
  },1000);

  runningAnimation = { animation: animation, voyageID: voyageID, voyageClass: voyageClass };

  //add image
  d3.select("#images_" + voyageID)
    .append("img")
    .attr("src", function(d){return  d.values[j].groupPic })
    .attr("width", "40");
  }

    });

  }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my sample data:

```
VoyageID,arrivalDateTxt,year,placeName,groupPic
1,14 January 1906,1906,Place 1,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,1 May 1907,1906,Place 2,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,26 October 1907,1906,Place 3,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,4 November 1907,1906,Place 4,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,26 November 1907,1906,Place 5,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,3 December 1907,1906,Place 6,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,10 December 1907,1906,Place 7,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,20 December 1907,1906,Place 8,ANMS1113[006].jpg
1,26 December 1907,1906,Place 9,ANMS1113[006].jpg
3,12 March 1845,1845,Island 1,00038301_4.jpg
3,15 March 1845,1845,Island 2,00038301_4.jpg
3,22 March 1845,1845,Place in ocean 3,00038301_4.jpg
3,23 July 1845,1845,Place in ocean 4,00038301_4.jpg
3,19 December 1845,1845,Place in ocean 5,00038301_4.jpg
3,22 January 1846,1845,Place in ocean 6,00038301_4.jpg
3,30 January 1846,1845,Back home,00038301_4.jpg
```

Comment: nor very handy to change the DOM above the buttons, as soon as you hover over the button it jumps and you lose the hover

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your help. Your solution does work in my sample so wil try to replicate it in my bigger project. Can you please tell me what you mean by you comment about problems with changing the DOM above the buttons? Grateful for ideas on how to improve this code generally.

Comment: #mapdata is above the #buttons so the buttons move if you add text to #mapdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't set the `background-color` to red

```
d3.select("#button_" + voyageClass).style("background-color", "red");
```

remove the style in `stopAnimation`

```
d3.select("#button_" + voyageClass).style("background-color", null);
```